# Design tokens doesn't work in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css3, design-tokens

I'm trying to use Lightning Tokens as described in [Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/interop_components_css_aura), but unfortunately, it can't resolve the reference.

I tried wrapping LWC component with Aura component it. Using tokens works in Aura component, but doesn't work in LWC.

Testing scenario:

**Tokens:**

```html
<!--tokens-->
<aura:tokens>
    <aura:token name="testBgColor" value="#e7e7e7"/>
</aura:tokens>
```

**Aura Wrapper**

```html
<aura:component description="auraWrapper" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <c:lwcTest/>
</aura:component>
```

**lwcTest.html**

```html
<template>
   <div class="test">Hello World</div>
</template>
```

**lwcTest.css**

```css
.test {
    background-color: var(--lwc-testBgColor, red);
}
```

It always shows component in `red`.

Did someone manage to make it work?

Regards.

**UPDATE**

Salesforce finally adding support for LWC design attributes in [Spring'20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lwc_custom_aura_tokens.htm)

So we can finally consider this issue resolved

**UPDATE**
Didn't work when I was last testing. But it's possible to define your own variables using standard CSS syntax.

local:

```
:host {
     --lwc-blue: #101556;
}
```

global:

```
:root {
     --lwc-blue: #101556;
}
```

you can't use :root in LWC directly, so you'll need to put it into Static Resource and load with [loadStyle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader/documentation).

Since I needed backward compatibility with CSS variables and wanted to work with them I started using SASS for them. My current setup.

root.scss

```
@import "vars";

:root {
  @each $property, $value in $vars {
    --lwc-#{$property}: #{$value};
  }
}
```

_vars.scss

```
$vars: (
 myBlue: #131355,
 red: #671010,
)
```

_base.scss

```
@import "vars";

@function var1($variable) {
  @return var(--lwc-#{$variable}, map-get($vars, $variable));
}
```

LWC component:
component.scss

```
@import "../base";

.container{
  border: 1px dotted var1(myBlue);
}
```

generated component.css

```
.container {
  border: 1px dotted var(--lwc-myBlue, #131355);
}
```

Hope it was a little bit helpful.

Comment: Could you try removing `extends="forceCommunity:base"` from the `aura:tokens` an see how it behaves?

Comment: @Raul nah, still doesn't work

Comment: Looks like a bug or something missing in documentation. Hope someone has a better insight.

Comment: Where are your tokens? They should be in the Aura wrapper, right?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor they are created with a name `defaultTokens.tokens`. You can't directly put them  in aura component, even though it is written so in Developer Guide

Comment: @ytiq It definitely doesn't seem to work as documented, have you tried reaching out to the Salesforce Support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT 12/22/2019: keep an eye on the release notes for spring '20, they're still in preview so this could change, but looks like a fix is coming.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lwc_custom_aura_tokens.htm

---

I suspect that it's not working yet. I noticed that in this link

[Lighting Web Component Custom Design Token is not getting rendered properly](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261789/lighting-web-component-custom-design-token-is-not-getting-rendered-properly)

Diego mentions that

"The problem is quite tricky to fix so it will probably land in Winter (September release)"

and that

"It’s an internal big number, can’t share it here"

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce finally adding support for LWC design attributes in [Spring'20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lwc_custom_aura_tokens.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you get the error: `No TOKEN named tokenName found`, it's likely that you're using a token that isn't marked Global Access.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_design_tokens

Answer (score -1):

To use standard salesforce design tokens in your lwc component, use

**background-color** : var(--lwc-colorBackgroundButtonBrand);

Where "var" is a CSS function used to access the token, "--lwc-" is a prefix you need to use and "colorBackgroundButtonBrand" is the token name

To get all the supported Community tokens, go [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_standard_communities.htm)

To get all the base salesforce design tokens, go [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_standard_force_base.htm)

Hope this helps!